# Why will this powermock not work even though it is syntactically correct?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

im trying to use power mocking to test my class

this is my class:

```
 public Basket createBasket(Basket basket) {
        if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.info("In BasketInformationServiceImpl.createBasket : [" + basket.toString() + "]");
        }
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(basket.getBasketAdditionsAllowedInd())) {
                basket.setBasketAdditionsAllowedInd("Y");
            }
```

this is my test:

```
public void testCreateBasketCallsSetBasketAdditionsAllowedIndInBasket(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StringUtils.class);
        when(StringUtils.isBlank(mockBasket.getBasketAdditionsAllowedInd())).thenReturn(true);
        basketInformationServiceImpl.createBasket(mockBasket);
        verify(mockBasket,times(1)).setBasketAdditionsAllowedInd(anyString());
    }
```

and the error i get is:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.missing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue;
Boolean cannot be returned by getBasketAdditionsAllowedInd()
getBasketAdditionsAllowedInd() should return string
```

does anyone know why i am getting this error and how to overcome it?

p.s. using power mock as StringUtils is a static class

Answer (score 0):

Have you mocked mockBasket.getBasketAdditionsAllowedInd somewhere else?

If so, try splitting the offending line in two parts.

```
String allowedInd = mockBasket.getBasketAdditionsAllowedInd();
when(StringUtils.isBlank(allowedInd)).thenReturn(true);
```

Why are you mocking a static class anyway?